# SafeAreaView measure function not working in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, view, measure

my problem is that I have to measure `View` using the basic `measure` function. However, if `SafeArea` uses that function, it will not work.

```js
const headerRef = useRef(null);
...
  useEffect(() => {
    headerRef.current.measure( (ox, oy, width, height, px, py) => {
    set({
      ox: ox,
      oy: oy,
      width: width,
      height: height,
      px: px,
      py: py,
    });
  };);
  }, []);
...
<SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea} ref={headerRef}>
```

**Error is**

```
TypeError : Cannot read property 'measure' of undefined
```

How can you solve this problem?

Is there anyone who has the same problem as me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using just `View`, not `SafeAreaView`. `SafeAreaView` doesn't seem to apply this part.

```js
const headerRef = useRef(null);
...
  useEffect(() => {
    headerRef.current.measure(getViewSize); 
  }, []);
...
const getViewSize = (ox, oy, width, height, px, py) => {
    set({
      ox: ox,
      oy: oy,
      width: width,
      height: height,
      px: px,
      py: py,
    });
  };
...
<View style={styles.safeArea} ref={headerRef}>
```

> Edit use onLayout

- sample

```
<View style={styles.safeArea} onLayout={({
                    nativeEvent: {
                        layout: { width, height, x, y }
                    }
                }) => console.log(width, height, x, y)}>
```

ref : https://reactnative.dev/docs/layoutevent

Comment: i got all undefined

Comment: @famfamfam you can use onLayout